TomEEhosting Error org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource:Provider org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.config.ServletConfigSource not a subtype
I developed a Java EE project using Glassfish 4.1.1. The project is basically a restful web services. Major libraries used: Jersey Framework, JPA, JAXB.
Now I am trying to host a project on Apache TomEE 8.0.16.
But I am getting following error continuously and couldn't find any solution for that over the internet.
Can anyone please help me in this regard?
Error is given below:
27-Aug-2024 15:26:27.745 SEVERE [main] org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication CDI Beans module deployment failed
org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansConfigurationException: Error while sending SystemEvent to a CDI Extension! org.apache.webbeans.portable.events.discovery.BeforeBeanDiscoveryImpl@40a7c0cc
at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.onWebBeansException(NotificationManager.java:1079)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.doFireSync(NotificationManager.java:1026)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.doFireEvent(NotificationManager.java:952)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.fireEvent(NotificationManager.java:928)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:495)
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireLifecycleEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:490)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.fireBeforeBeanDiscoveryEvent(BeansDeployer.java:805)
at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:244)
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.OpenEJBLifecycle.startApplication(OpenEJBLifecycle.java:196)
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:269)
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder.build(CdiBuilder.java:43)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:974)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:762)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1340)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1162)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4820)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:582)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource: Provider org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.config.ServletConfigSource not a subtype
at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:377)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.invokeObserverMethod(NotificationManager.java:1146)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.doFireSync(NotificationManager.java:1009)
... 55 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource: Provider org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.config.ServletConfigSource not a subtype
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
at org.apache.geronimo.config.DefaultConfigBuilder.build(DefaultConfigBuilder.java:130)
at org.apache.geronimo.config.DefaultConfigProvider.getConfig(DefaultConfigProvider.java:62)
at org.apache.geronimo.config.DefaultConfigProvider.getConfig(DefaultConfigProvider.java:46)
at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.getConfig(ConfigProvider.java:93)
at org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.openapi.config.OpenAPIConfigMpConfigImpl.(OpenAPIConfigMpConfigImpl.java:29)
at org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.openapi.config.GeronimoOpenAPIConfig.create(GeronimoOpenAPIConfig.java:26)
at org.apache.geronimo.microprofile.openapi.cdi.GeronimoOpenAPIExtension.init(GeronimoOpenAPIExtension.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.invoke(ObserverMethodImpl.java:410)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.ContainerEventObserverMethodImpl.invoke(ContainerEventObserverMethodImpl.java:86)
at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:371)
... 57 more
27-Aug-2024 15:26:27.745 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/soulwebapit]
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: couldn't start owb context
at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.initialize(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:271)
I tried to change the versions of the libraries as well as I tried to add the microprofile libraries as a dependencies in pom.xml and removed the same libraries from TomEE "libs" folder.
Nothing worked for me.
Added all the libraries in pom.xml
The main question is WHY IT IS NOT WORKING WITH APACHE TOMEE whereas IT IS WORKING FINE WITH GLASSFISH.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
